# how to add primary key to table having duplicate values?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with structure

**Table-a** Id was primary key

```
ID | Name
1  | Gourav
2  | Amit
3  | Rahul
```

But After that primary key automatically removed by restoring database to other database..

Now Records in Table are

```
ID | Name
1  | Gourav
2  | Amit
3  | Rahul
0  | AAA
0  | BBB
0  | CCC
```

How can i add primary key to id column again and can handle the existing data as well in MYSQL.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add PK as AUTO_INCREMENT, it will change all 0 values automatically -

```
ALTER TABLE table_a
  CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

After, AUTO_INCREMENT property can be removed -

```
ALTER TABLE table_a
  CHANGE COLUMN id id INT(11) NOT NULL;
```